# ngIf throwing error message as soon as I refresh

Tags: angularjs, validation, visual-studio-code, angular-ng-if

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <form #userForm="ngForm">


        <div class="form-group row varun">

            <div class="form-group">

                <input type="email" required #email="ngModel" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$" [class.is-invalid]="email.invalid && email.touched " class="form-control " ngModel placeholder="Email " name="email ">
                <div *ngIf="email.errors && (email.invalid || email.touched)">
                    <small class="text-danger" *ngIf="email.errors.required">Cannot call to BLANK number</small>
                    <small class="text-danger" *ngIf="email.errors.pattern">Oops! PAgers are out dated, Enter a 10 digit Mobile</small>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- <input type="password" class="form-control" ngModel name="password" value="" placeholder="password" /> -->
            <div class="form-group">

                <input type="password" required pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}$" #password="ngModel" [class.is-invalid]="password.invalid && password.touched" class="form-control" ngModel placeholder="Password" name="password">
                <div *ngIf="password.errors && (password.invalid || password.touched )">
                    <small class="text-danger" *ngIf="password.errors.required">Cannot call to BLANK number</small>
                    <small class="text-danger" *ngIf="password.errors.pattern">Oops! PAgers are out dated, Enter a 10 digit Mobile</small>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- <div class="form-group">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" style="width: 20vw; height: 3vh;">
            </div> -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>

        </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

As soon as I refresh my page, it's displaying the Error messaged present in the  tag for the Error Validation. I have used Angular8, HTML. Please help me through this.

Comment: What is the error message you are getting ?

Comment: If your validation messages are coming up everytime its likley your logic `email.errors && (email.invalid || email.touched)`. Shouldnt this be `email.errors && (email.invalid && email.touched) to ensure its only shown once the input has been touched? Also look at `$dirty` for an alternative